# Storing XML values other than IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am storing XML values in IEnumerable like this

```
   public static IEnumerable bindstate()
    {
        var states = from b in getdata().Descendants("state").SelectMany(state => state.Elements("text"))
        orderby (string)  b
        select  (string) b;

        return states;

    }
```

Is there any other way to store values other than IEnumerable?

Comment: You mean like `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: Yes i am having problem using IEnumerable so any suggestions other than this?Even i used IEnumerable<XElement> even it dint worked.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Your query is already of type `IEnumerable<string>`, just change the return type to that.

Comment: I mean in which other ways we can store store the data?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, by storing values into other types of IEnumerable. 
I think if you change the return type from

```
IEnumerable
```

to

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

that will help you out.

If you wanted I tihnk you could return a `List<string>` also and add

```
return states.ToList();
```

to the return statment to return a List os strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "materialize" the `IEnumerable<T>` to:

1. `List<T>`: use `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`: `return states.ToList();`.
2. `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (implements `IList<T>` interface): use `IEnumerable<T>.AsReadOnly()`: `return states.AsReadOnly();`. As it comes from its name, the returned list is read only.

In both cases the preferred return types of the `bindstate` method are `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.